# Are state variables copied during inheritance?

Tags: solidity

I am testing. Looks to me like state variables are copied during inheritance.

Also when I use new, I am unsure what happens to state variables.

I have d13 state as car - bool. It is updated by d13. When I update using d12 I do not have a new state definition in d12 but it looks like a new state variable is defined in d12 (see storage display).

When I use d14, it looks like another new state variable is defined but I cannot even find that one.

Does anyone know how state variables are inherited and held in storage? What is the point of a design which copies the state variable definition into the new contract?

Code -

> ```
> contract d13 {
>     bool public car;
>     function setCar() public returns (bool) {
>         car=true;
>         return car;
>     }
>
>     function removeCar() public returns (bool) {
>         car=false;
>         return car;
>     }
>     function showMemory() pure returns (uint) {
>         uint ms;
>         assembly {
>            ms := msize()
>         }
>         return ms;
>     }
> }
>
>
> contract d12 is d13 {
>     function isCar() public view returns (bool) {
>         return car; 
>     }
>
>     function newCar() public {
>         car=true;
>     }
>
>     function oldCar() public {
>         car=false;
>     }
>     function showMemory() pure returns (uint) {
>         uint ms;
>         assembly {
>            ms := msize()
>         }
>         return ms;
>     }
> }
>
> contract d14 {
>     function isCar() view returns (bool) {
>         return (new d13()).car();
>     }
>
>     function setCar() returns (bool) {
>         d13 d13instance = new d13();
>         d13instance.setCar();
>         return (d13instance.car());
>     }
>     function showMemory() pure returns (uint) {
>         uint ms;
>         assembly {
>            ms := msize()
>         }
>         return ms;
>     }
>
> }
> ```

Geth -

```
> eth.getStorageAt(d13con.address,0)
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"
> d13con.car()
true
> d13con.removeCar()
"0x01973e61dbbf3b44994b016122afc1bd6d94ab2476042aed8902eeca01b6ed80"
> d13con.car()
false
> d12con.isCar()
true
> d12con.oldCar()
"0x09bebed58d84621ac18ae6820634f7678be7b8514dd029b5685ec514f552342d"
> eth.pendingTransactions.length
1
> eth.pendingTransactions.length
1
> eth.pendingTransactions.length
0
> d12con.isCar()
false
> eth.getStorageAt(d13con.address,0)
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
> d13con.setCar()
"0x9b425c7640c06dc8faf66976ba07ef53c7d8a2a8c362ae75756192c78076a65c"
> eth.pendingTransactions.length
0
> d13con.car()
true
> d12con.isCar()
false
> eth.getStorageAt(d12con.address,0)
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
> d12con.newCar()
"0x300d0c641711436bc60add13b7e101e8acc22305704de4a16bd466db61dce37a"
> d12con.isCar()
false
> eth.pendingTransactions.length
0
> eth.getStorageAt(d12con.address,0)
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"
> d12con.isCar()
true
> eth.getStorageAt(d13con.address,0)
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"
> d14con.isCar()
false
> eth.getStorageAt(d14con.address,0)
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
> d14con.setCar()
"0x71a896c7822a0413d64df03e96fdce1e77f61425e3a86124948dc99cda2718f6"
> eth.pendingTransactions.length
0
> d14con.isCar()
false
> eth.getStorageAt(d14con.address,0)
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

I set a contract instance as d12con etc for d12.

Comment: Does it just copy the entire inherited contract into the inheriting one? What is the point of this?

Answer (score 1):

I tested this and it seems that the inheriting contract basically takes a complete copy of the inherited contract.

Hence d12 actually updates the car state variable in d12 but it's not explicitly defined in d12.